# Can not access to google cloud persistent disk or snapshot. It stuck

Tags: google-compute-engine

My vm instance on google cloud ce got stuck, I could not connect to it anyway. So I tried to take a snapshot of my SSD persistent disk. And It get stuck too. Then I deleted the vm instance, and then the disk and snapshot have remained.

- Now I can not delete the snapshot,
  It says that the snapshot is not ready.
- I can not use the disk on another vm instance,
  It says that the disk resource *** is already being used in locked mode.

What can I do now? How can I access the data on the disk. Two hours have already passed, snapshot is still not ready. How can I force the snapshot to cancel or delete?

Thank you.

Here are some outputs of gcloud :

```
$ gcloud compute snapshots delete snapshot-1
The following snapshots will be deleted:
 - [snapshot-1]

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.snapshots.delete) Some requests did not succeed:
 - The resource 'projects/macellan-1/global/snapshots/snapshot-1' is not ready
```

-

```
$ gcloud compute snapshots describe snapshot-1
creationTimestamp: '2014-09-12T04:34:55.800-07:00'
description: yedek
diskSizeGb: '30'
id: '66028031121729*****'
kind: compute#snapshot
name: snapshot-1
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/macellan-1/global/snapshots/snapshot-1
sourceDisk: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/macellan-1/zones/europe-west1-b/disks/macellan-gc-1
sourceDiskId: '168047495895058*****'
status: UPLOADING
```

-

```
$ gcloud compute disks describe macellan-gc-1
creationTimestamp: '2014-08-01T01:57:30.290-07:00'
id: '168047495895058*****'
kind: compute#disk
name: macellan-gc-1
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/macellan-1/zones/europe-west1-b/disks/macellan-gc-1
sizeGb: '30'
sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/backports-debian-7-wheezy-v20140718
sourceImageId: '125772519469419*****'
status: READY
type: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/macellan-1/zones/europe-west1-b/diskTypes/pd-ssd
zone: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/macellan-1/zones/europe-west1-b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a service disruption related with SSD in europe-west1-b right now.

You'll have more information at [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-operations/i_Cj6vLYR2o). In that thread you'll be able to see when the issue is solved and after few days you'll know what was the root cause and what has been done to prevent it from happening again.

Comment: Thank you. It looks the issue has been solved for me now. Everything is working fine.

Comment: It appears that the problem still exists at least for me. I'm getting exactly the same response for my project.

Comment: @Randy: It seems that you have been affected by this [other issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-operations/5fcSh8wy-FQ).